# Difference between Truth and Fact

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, truth

I was interested in the difference between truth and fact. For me, truth is a belief that appears to be from a perspective. and a fact is an undeniable reality.

Is this way of thinking correct? How would i differentiate truth and facts?

Comment: See [Facts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/facts/): "Facts, philosophers like to say, are opposed to theories and to values and are to be distinguished from things, in particular from complex objects, complexes and wholes, and from relations. They are the objects of certain mental states and acts, they make truth-bearers true and correspond to truths, they are part of the furniture of the world."

Comment: And see [Truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth/): "a belief or proposition or sentence is true if there exists an appropriate entity – a fact – to which it corresponds. If there is no such entity, the belief is false."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the definition of truth is where my confusion comes from, if for something to be true, it has to be in accordance with reality and facts, why has "truth" been so relative throughout history.

Before pythagoras's theory of a spherical earth, the truth was that the earth is flat, but the modern truth is different, does this imply that our understanding of truth is dependent on our prespective or reference of frame?

Comment: Truth is one of most debated philosophical issues... Most of us assume that there is a *reality* (facts) independent form our will and point of view, and thus a statement/belief is true if it "corresponds" in some sense to reality. I'm written "most of us" :-)

Answer (score -2):

"Fact" is a noun. A fact is a proposition or possibly a state of affairs expressed by a proposition. "True" is an adjective. "Truth" is just the nounified form of the adjective. a property of a proposition. There isn't a difference in meaning, only a difference in grammatical category.

The difference is very definitely not that one is subjective/relative and the other is objective/absolute.